# Modal Windows Forms in Office

Tags: vb.net, forms, listview, modal-dialog, modeless

I have a modal Windows form created in VB.NET that I am using for a PowerPoint add-in (this issue would also apply to an Excel add-in, I suspect).  The form lets the user select shapes on the current slide from a `ListView` object.  With each selection, the corresponding shape should be selected on the current slide.  I know that my code is identifying the proper shape, but the Select statement won't work when appended to the shape object.  Presumably, this is because the form is modal, not modeless.

Without making the form modeless, is there a way to actually select shape on the slide corresponding to the selected ListView item?  Perhaps there is a way to "refresh" the application (e.g. PowerPoint) while the form is open to reflect the shape selection?

Alternatively, is there a way to make the form modeless while behaving like a modal form?  The form in question is "owned" by another modal Windows form, complicating matters.

Comment: Can you post some code example for this?